# Add an onClick that calls a function externally from HTML to JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my HTML:

```
<form name="imageForm">
  <table border=3>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input onclick="displayImage();" type=button value="Display Random Image">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="trinit5.js"></script>
    </td>
  </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

How do I link this piece of HTML code to this following JavaScript file? I want add an onClick event handler that calls the displayImage function

```
var imagesArray = ["thumbs/lrgokublack.png", "thumbs/lrtrunks.png", "thumbs/lrgohan.png", "thumbs/lrmajinvegeta.png"];

function displayImage(){

    var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
    document.canvas.src = imagesArray[num];

}
```

Comment: looks like your displayImage function is getting executed...document.canvas is undefined (are you missing some markup?)

Comment: yeah, in inspect element it says there's an error with document.canvas, but i don't know what any of this means, as I took this piece of code from online D:

Comment: Get your script tag out of the `<td>` element,  It doesn't belong there.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var imagesArray = ["thumbs/lrgokublack.png", "thumbs/lrtrunks.png", "thumbs/lrgohan.png", "thumbs/lrmajinvegeta.png"];

function displayImage() {
  var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * imagesArray.length);
  window.canvas.src = imagesArray[num];
}
```

```html
<input onclick="displayImage()" type=button value="Display Random Image">
<img id="canvas"></img>
```

Comment: Could use some explanation, imagesArray.length instead of `5` is a good call.